# how to get scheduled posts by date with the twitter api?

Tags: twitter

I have been working with the twitter api to create an app for scheduling posts. I have been having no trouble with creating scheduled posts but is there a way that anyone knows of to fetch scheduled posts by date range?

The API documentation doesn't specify any means to do so so am assuming that is just not possible?

Link to docs -> https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/creatives/api-reference/scheduled-tweets#get-accounts-account-id-scheduled-tweets

Comment: There is no API option to do this.

Comment: @AndyPiper is there a recommended way to go about implementing this myself? My idea would be that I would need to create some kind of scheduling system myself so that I can get tweets by date.